# How would I take an image on one activity and move it into another activity

Tags: android

If I grid view of many images and the user selects one images and click next. How would I move the selected image from one screen into another screen. for example on the intro screen I have a image of a puppy and I click on that image that makes it go into another activity but how would I transfer that images into the second activity?

What I have tried doing is that I have tired doing it by the same principle of moving strings from one activity to another but no luck on that one.

Thank You,

Harsh

Comment: Why do you send the whole image on click? instead you can try sending the image url to the next activity on click.

Comment: Send the image url as a string and load it in the other activity.  It's not good to send entire bitmaps because they're sometimes too big.

Answer (score 0):

To write

```
byte[] imgByteArray = ... convert Bitmap to byte array
Intent I = new Intent(YourActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("imgBytes", imgByteArray);
startActivity(i);
```

To read

```
Bundle extras = getExtras();
byte[] imgByteArray = extras.getByteArray("imgBytes");
Bitmap bitmap = ... convert byte array to Bitmap
```

Ideally it would be better to use some kind of image caching library like Picasso or Universal Image Loader for better memory handling and so you could pass image url instead of bytes.

Comment: This is awesome think you so much guys :)